# Latch-Up in CMOS Design

Tags: cmos, vlsi

I am currently stock on a concept I should understand but I cannot get my head around it quite yet: "Latch-up" in CMOS devices.  It is a condition where a significant amount of current flows through Si substrate of NMOS and PMOS parts of a CMOS structure.  By having a high conductivity path from VDD to GND in the CMOS structure, you could potentially damage the device and it would never recover.

So with this definition in my head, I am trying to figure out factors that will help me prevent latch-up in CMOS devices.  Also, why does the conception of CMOS technology in SOI substrates ultimately prevent latch-up?

Thanks in advance for the tips

Comment: Instead of me explaining this phenomenon, have you read the Wikipedia page about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up ? Also ways to prevent latch-up are mentioned there: substrate contacts, isolation structures etc.

Comment: I do not think that SOI technology prevents Latch-up from happening. The structures are the same as in a non-SOI process only isolated from the main substrate. So I think it is still possible to make a thyristor-like structure and latch-up occuring under some circumstances.

Comment: @FakeMoustache -- in SOI processing, you can also isolate the NMOS and PMOS structures *from each other*, or at least that's my understanding of how it works.  (Obviously, trench isolation is also effective against latchup for the same exact reason.)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel OK, I'm not so familiar with SOI so didn't realize that. I suppose that if it was possible to make an isolated N-well for the PMOS (meaning not a P-well containing an N-well containing a PMOS like in non-SOI) then indeed there can be no PNPN structures so then you would not have the thyristor.